# How to create a pivot/panorama app in Windowsphone8 by Worklight

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, pivot, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm new in worklight, and try to dev an app for wp8. But i dont know how to make  pivot/panorama style for app in this platform. 
anyone can help me ???

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help fist. You should provide something you tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question about creating a Pivot/Panorama app on phone gap here: [How do I create a simple panorama application for Windows Phone 7 using PhoneGap/Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493449/how-do-i-create-a-simple-panorama-application-for-windows-phone-7-using-phonegap)
Much of the discussion there will apply to Worklight also.  Amongst other things, there seems to be an attempt to implement a Panorama like control in jQuery: https://github.com/grohman/js-panorama

IScroll seems to be another option: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4