# can use phonegap to call windows phone maps?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm new in worklight, and try to dev an app for wp8. i've tried to call windows phone map  in this platform by using phonegap, but i'm not successful.

Anyone can help me this?

Comment: how you were not successful?

Comment: i'm very cloudy about that, actually i don't know exactly to do call back maps from c# file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. But, It's not so easy if you're newbie on Windows Phone Development. Below, I suggests a link for you where you can find code and tutorial how do achieve this. All the best.

http://www.christianengvall.se/phonegap-and-google-maps/

Here, more links for you.

Resources

The popular PhoneGap open source mobile framework support for Windows Phone 7.5 is complete and available for download: https://github.com/cordova/cordova-windows-phone

Additional PhoneGap plugins that support social networks - Facebook, LinkedIn, Windows Live, Twitter and mapping (Bing Map launcher) - are now available for download [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/WindowsPhone).

Technical details from PhoneGap.com: PhoneGap for Windows Phone Dissected http://www.risingj.com/archives/147

Get Started with PhoneGap on Windows Phone 7.5: 
http://PhoneGap.com/start#wp

Video published on Youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1aqYKd5rxr8

Video published on Channel 9 http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Interoperability

Series of tips posts on Glen Gordon’s blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/glengordon/

Jesse MacFayden’s blog (PhoneGap’s dev lead): http://risingj.com/

Other resources:

WP7 Porting resources and API mapping:  http://windowsphone.interopbridges.com/

“Leveraging your iPhone development expertise to build Windows Phone applications”  http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/04/29/leveraging-your-iphone-development-expertise-to-build-windows-phone-7-applications.aspx

“Leveraging your Android development expertise to build Windows Phone applications” http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/06/09/leveraging-your-android-development-expertise-to-build-windows-phone-applications.aspx

If this link helps you, Don't forget to Mark this as an answer.

Comment: i've already found some links that you've provided, but the key's in here that are i want to call HERE Maps in my app, not google maps.

i've done a panorama style for my app by using phonegap
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493449/how-do-i-create-a-simple-panorama-application-for-windows-phone-7-using-phonegap

My app has a page for maps. I don't know how to when i drag from another page to maps page, HERE maps should be visible.